# Counting combinations in Dataframe create new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics

So I have a dataframe called reactions_drugs

[image]

and I want to create a table called new_r_d where I keep track of how often a see a symptom for a given medication like

[image]

Here is the code I have but I am running into errors such as "Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 3 given 0"

```
new_r_d = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['drugname', 'reaction', 'count']

for i in range(len(reactions_drugs)):
        name = reactions_drugs.drugname[i]
        drug_rec_act = reactions_drugs.drug_rec_act[i]
        for rec in drug_rec_act:
            row = new_r_d.loc[(new_r_d['drugname'] == name) & (new_r_d['reaction'] == rec)]
            if row == []:
                # create new row
                new_r_d.append({'drugname': name, 'reaction': rec, 'count': 1})
            else:
                new_r_d.at[row,'count'] += 1
```

Comment: You should probably remove actual drug names from your example data, as it is most likely confidential data.

Comment: Good point! I believe it is nonconfidential since the data is publicly accessible though: https://www.fda.gov/drugs/questions-and-answers-fdas-adverse-event-reporting-system-faers/fda-adverse-event-reporting-system-faers-public-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rows in your current reactions (drug_rec_act) column contain one string enclosed in a list, you can convert the values in that column to lists of strings (by splitting each string on the comma delimiter) and then utilize the `explode()` function and `value_counts()` to get your desired result:

```
df['drug_rec_act'] = df['drug_rec_act'].apply(lambda x: x[0].split(','))

df_long = df.explode('drug_rec_act')

result = df_long.groupby('drugname')['drug_rec_act'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
```